# How do I get a result set in a MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

On `BEFORE` `INSERT` I'm trying to check the values. If a column is blank, I want to load in the default value - based on a row in a separate table. I though something like my code below would do what I needed but I'm getting an error.

> Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger Execution stopped!

This is my SQL, I assume its complaining about my select statement.

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_Sites_ID` BEFORE INSERT ON Sites
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT @CA:=Palette0ColorA,  @CB:=Palette0ColorB FROM Themes WHERE ID=NEW.ThemeID;
  SET NEW.ID = UUID();
  SET NEW.ColorA = IF(NEW.ColorA = '', @CA, NEW.ColorA);
  SET NEW.ColorB = IF(NEW.ColorB = '', @CB, NEW.ColorB);
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: did you change the delimiter?

Comment: Mr. Justin, did eggyal's answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SELECT` is, as the error message implies, attempting to return data to the client.  You could instead use [`SELECT ... INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html):

```
SELECT Palette0ColorA, Palette0ColorB INTO @CA, @CB FROM Themes WHERE ID=NEW.ThemeID
```